# AngularJS app works on localhost but throws errors on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I have an angularJS quiz application that works fine on localhost. Once uploaded to a live server the app doesnt load and the console fires an error. I have no idea what could be wrong as the app is working locally. Here is the error:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=%5B%24compile%3Abaddir%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.3%2F%24compile%2Fbaddir%3Fp0%3Dng%2520%0AM%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A425%0Ac%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A16055%0Ay%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A16467%0AIc%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A1416%0Ap%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A1201%0Ay%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A16968%0ACe%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A3365%0Ainvoke%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A10908%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A9758%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A9905%0Ap%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A1011%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A9667%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A11811%0Ac%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A3%3A373%0APc%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A3%3A686%0Aue%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A2%3A5429%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A9%3A72076%0Ai%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A27444%0AfireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A28213%0Aready%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A30004%0AK%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A30366%0A
```

Does anyone have any insights? I have developed the quiz as a wordpress plugin with some variables localized to the angular script.

I am using angular 1.6 with angular route. Some of my code is below:

```
    (function(){

/*
 * Declaration of main angular module for this appllication.
 *
 * It is named quiz and has no dependencies (hence the 
 * empty array as the second argument)
 */
angular
    .module("quiz", []);

    })();
```

Controllers:

```
    (function () {

angular
        .module("quiz")
        .controller("quizCtrl", QuizController);


QuizController.$inject = ['quizmanager'];

function QuizController(quizmanager) 
{
    ...
```

Controllers:

```
    (function () {

angular
        .module("quiz")
        .controller("resultsCtrl", ResultsController);

ResultsController.$inject = ['quizmanager'];

function ResultsController(quizmanager) 
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.quizmanager = quizmanager; 

}


    })();
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    (function () {

angular
        .module("quiz")
        .controller("welcomeCtrl", WelcomeController);

WelcomeController.$inject = ['quizmanager'];

function WelcomeController(quizmanager) 
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.quizmanager = quizmanager; 

    vm.activateQuiz = activateQuiz; 
    /*
     * STARTING POINT OF APPLICATION. All the other views are hidden
     */
    quizmanager.loadQuiz();

    function activateQuiz() 
    {

        quizmanager.changeState("quiz", true);
        quizmanager.countdown();
      }
    }


    })();
```

Based on your responses, heres where i think the problem lies:

FACTORIES:

```
    (function () {


angular
        .module("quiz")
        .factory("quizmanager", QuizManager)
        .filter('formatTimer', function () {
            return function (input)
            {
                function z(n) {
                    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
                }
                var seconds = input % 60;
                var minutes = Math.floor(input / 60);
                var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                return (z(hours) + ':' + z(minutes) + ':' + z(seconds));
            };
        });


QuizManager.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout', '$httpParamSerializer', '$filter']; 
    ......
```

I have modified the app and added the filter as a  seperate module like so:

```
    (function () {


angular
        .module("quiz")
        .filter('formatTimer', function () {
            return function (input)
            {
                function z(n) {
                    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
                }
                var seconds = input % 60;
                var minutes = Math.floor(input / 60);
                var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                return (z(hours) + ':' + z(minutes) + ':' + z(seconds));
            };
        });



    })();
```

The app still works in localhost but Im still getting an error:

```
     Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=%5B%24compile%3Abaddir%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.3%2F%24compile%2Fbaddir%3Fp0%3Dng%2520%0AM%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A425%0Ac%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A16055%0Ay%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A16467%0AIc%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A1416%0Ap%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A1201%0Ay%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A16968%0ACe%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A3365%0Ainvoke%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A10908%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A9758%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A9905%0Ap%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A1%3A1011%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A9667%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A4%3A11811%0Ac%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A3%3A373%0APc%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A3%3A686%0Aue%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A2%3A5429%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Feot_quiz%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%2Cqver%3D1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js%3A9%3A72076%0Ai%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A27444%0AfireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A28213%0Aready%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A30004%0AK%40http%3A%2F%2Fexpertonlinetraining.info%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%2Cqver%3D1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js%3A1%3A30366%0A  angular.min.js,qver=1.0.0.pagespeed.jm.L2GCHQP8hk.js:1:425
```

Comment: Check your network requests, and let us know if there's anything failing.

Comment: Without more information, it's going to be really tough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You say it works on localhost. Do you mean the exact same files that get deployed to the server work on the localhost? Or are the files deployed to the server optimized versions of the files that work locally?

Comment: Its the exact same files from localhost

Comment: On the live server, the image requests to some interface elements are failing (404) on the network but the images are in fact on the live server

Comment: It loads in chrome but I get the console error:
/dashboard/%7B%7Bwelcome.quizmanager.quiz_logo%7D%7D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Description

> This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some
>   exception. The error message above should provide additional context.
>
> A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten
>   to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't
>   be loaded.

Using ngRoute

> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to
>   its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x
>   or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

Monkey-patching AngularJS's ng module

> This error can also occur if you
>   have tried to add your own components to the ng module. This has never
>   been supported and from 1.3.0 it will actually trigger this error. For
>   instance the following code could trigger this error.
>
> angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function (){}); Instead create your
>   own module and add it as a dependency to your application's top-level
>   module. See #9692 and #7709 for more information

What version of AngularJS are you using? You might be running into the second issue description here.

Comment: I'm using angular 1.6 with angular route. I have my app seperated into seperate modules but yes I might be monkey patching one of my modules with a filter:

Comment: The app doesnt use ngRoute. It contains one main view with a few show hide directives